# Как описать структуру БД для связи одной таблицы с 2-я таблицами?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Здравствуйте,
есть таблица

```
class File 
{
  int Id { get; set; } 
  ...
}
```

которую надо связать с 2-я таблицами

```
class Table1 
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  ...
  int FileId { get; set; }
  File File { get; set; }
}
```

и

```
class Table2
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  ...
  int FileId { get; set; }
  File File { get; set; }
}
```

`EF` выдает ошибку

```
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Tables2_dbo.Files_FileId". The conflict occurred in database "dbContext-", table "dbo.Files", column 'Id'.
```

Полагаю, ошибка из-за того, что нету однозначного соответствия File.Id - Table2.FileId, его и не должно быть по задумке.
Как теперь правильно описать структуру БД?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

поля `FileId` должны быть не обязательными: **int? FileId**

```
class Table1 
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  ...
  int? FileId { get; set; }
  File File { get; set; }
}

class Table2
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  ...
  int? FileId { get; set; }
  File File { get; set; }
}
```